# start asynctask when fragment is shown

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have 3 fragments.

In onActivityCreated() of each fragment I execute an async task.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    mTaskGetPoints = new AsyncTaskGetFavouritePoints();
    mTaskGetPoints.execute();
}
```

The async task in doInBackground gets data from a SQLite DB and creates an ArrayList of objects. In onPostExecute I call a method to show the data on a listView.

Each fragment has its own asynctask.

When I "launch" the FragmentActivity the Fragment 1 is shown and its asynctask is executed. But its nearest fragment (Fragment 2, the middle fragment) also launches its AsyncTask.

I would like to know if is it possible to start the async task only when the user is seeing the fragment.
I would like if is it possible because I would like to show a progress dialog (getting data...).
Right now I have little data to get from database, but if I have a lot I would like to show a Progress Dialog. Right now if I show a ProgressDialog in onPreExecute of each asynctask, If a change to Fragment 2 from Fragment 1 I see on Fragment 2 the ProgressDialog of Fragment 3 :/

Maybe Im wrong and the use of asynctasks is bad.

Edit 1:
FragmentActivity

```
public class FragmentActivityInterestPoints extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener { 
    PagerAdapterInterestPoints mInterestPointsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.pager_adapter_fragment);
        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the app.
        mInterestPointsPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapterInterestPoints(
                getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mInterestPointsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager
                .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                    }
                });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mInterestPointsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                    .setText(mInterestPointsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

}


public class PagerAdapterInterestPoints extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private static final int PAGES = 3;

    private ArrayList<Fragment> pages = new ArrayList<Fragment>(PAGES);

    public PagerAdapterInterestPoints(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

        pages.add(new FragmentShowPoints());
        pages.add(new FragmentCategoryPoints());
        pages.add(new FragmentFavouritePoints());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show total pages.
        return PAGES;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return pages.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "Fragment 1";
        case 1:
            return "Fragment 2";
        case 2:
            return "Fragment 3";
        default:
            return "Undefined";
        }
    }

}


public class FragmentShowPoints extends ListFragment {
    private MyDatabase myDB;

    private ArrayList<PointInterest> listPoints = null;
    // UI
    private ListView lv;
    View rootView;
    ListAdapterShowPoints adapter;

    AsyncTaskGetPoints mTaskGetPoints;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private Activity act;

    public FragmentShowPoints() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_show_points, container,
                false);

        this.act = getActivity();

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Load UI
        lv = getListView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        mTaskGetPoints = new AsyncTaskGetPoints();
        mTaskGetPoints.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (mTaskGetPoints != null) {
            mTaskGetPoints.cancel(true);
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mTaskGetPoints != null) {
            mTaskGetPoints.cancel(true);
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    private void showPoints() { 
            adapter = new ListAdapterShowPoints(act, listPoints, act);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

    private class AsyncTaskGetPoints extends
            AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<PointInterest>> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(act);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<PointInterest> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            myDB = new MyDatabase(act);
            Cursor c = myDB.getPoints();
            //loop with data
            c.close();
            myDB.close();
            return listPoints;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<PointInterest> result) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            showPoints();
        }

    }
}



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/pager"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Edit 2 (My solution):
I used something more simple.

In the layout of each fragment I have added another layout inside with a progress bar and a text view. And in onResume I hide the listView and show the layout with the progress bar and text view. Also I do the same in onPreexecute of the asynctask (I supposed that only in this point should be ok because in onResume I start the asynctask (but I was testing haha)). In on postExecute, if I have data to show I hide the progress bar and the textview and I show the list view.
An important thing is do this in on UI thread, if not I get the next error: “Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.”

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (listPointsSearch == null) {
                        adapter = new ListAdapterShowPoints(act, listPoints,
                                act);
                    } else {
                        adapter = new ListAdapterShowPoints(act,
                                listPointsSearch, act);
                    }
                    adapter.setActivity(act);

                    setListAdapter(adapter);

                    lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    pRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
```

But only I have the problem in onPostExecute(). When a fragment is resumed but you are not seeing it, it works ok, I don't exactly why, because in onPreExecute should crash.

Edit 3: I should test with loaders too instead of asynctasks.

Comment: If the user isn't seeing your fragments, why are they even attached? How are your fragments structured? Is it a ViewPager? Tabs? How are you adding/switching between them? I'd recommend a loading view in the Fragment vs a DialogFragment; also to use Loaders instead of an AsyncTask to load the data. (this will handle orientation changes properly)

Comment: @kcoppock I have edited with my code. And thanks for the Loaders, I didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that depending on what you use to change your fragments (from what you're saying, I think you are using a `ViewPager`, aren't you?), it caches the fragment before showing them to the user, so that it's not to long to load the UI.

I'd say you'd better start your `AsyncTask` using a callback called when the fragment changes. You could have an interface, implemented by your Fragments, and called when you changes from one fragment to a new one.

**Edit**: More info from your code

First, create a simple callback interface implemented by your Fragments, that would start your AsyncTask.

```
public interface OnFragmentShownListener {
    void onFragmentShown();
}
```

Then, on your `SimpleOnPageChangeListener#onPageSelected`, call your `mInterestPointsPagerAdapter.getItem(position)` to retrieve the shown fragment.

Then, still in your onPageSelected you call your `((OnFragmentShownListener) fragment).onFragmentShown()` which should start your AsyncTask.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I have updated with my code. Yes I'm using a ViewPager. I have used callbacks and interfaces in other app, but this don't solve my problem, no? The problem is start the async task when the fragment is shown, not when the fragment is loaded but is "hidden". Thanks for your time

Comment: @Adrian Updated answer from your code. I didn't try it out, but I think this should work.

Comment: hi again, I edited with my solution. I have only one question. I don't know why in onPostExecute I must use runOnUiThread to avoid the app crashes but not in onPreExecute. Thanks